# How to correctly type the result of a findOne using typescript, sequelize and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, model, sequelize.js

I currently do the following search

```
const user: any = await UserModel.findOne({
   where: {
      email: email,
   },
});
```

I'm typing with **any** because I need to use some table columns like **user.username** and **user.password**, but I don't want to use **any**.

UserModel:

```
const UserModel = db.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  access_level: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  biography: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  profile_image: {
    type: DataTypes.BLOB("medium"),
    allowNull: true,
  },
});
```

I tried to create an **userInterface** to replace **any** but it didn't work

```
interface userAttributes {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  access_level: number;
  biography: string;
  profile_image: Blob;
}
```

Can you help me type the result of this findOne properly, please?

Comment: What error are you getting when you use interface? Can you show an example of your code using that interface?

Comment: May be you missed the `null` in the response which should be returned when no user is found

Comment: @W-B Type 'Model<any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'userAttributes'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'userAttributes'

Comment: @AhmedLazhar Type 'Model<any, any> | null' is not assignable to type 'userAttributes | null'.
  Type 'Model<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'userAttributes': id, username, email, password, and 3 more.ts(2322)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution reading sequelize doc: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/

the code in case anyone want to see:

```
import { CreationOptional, DataTypes, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, Model } from "sequelize";
import { db } from "../database/db-connection";

class UserModel extends Model<InferAttributes<UserModel>, InferCreationAttributes<UserModel>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare username: string;
  declare email: string;
  declare password: string;
  declare access_level: number;
  declare biography: string;
  declare profile_image: Blob | string;
  declare createdAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
  declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<Date>;
}

UserModel.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    access_level: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    biography: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    profile_image: {
      type: DataTypes.BLOB("medium"),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    sequelize: db,
    tableName: "users",
  }
);

export { UserModel };
```

```
      const user: UserModel | null = await UserModel.findOne({
        where: {
          id: id,
        },
      });
```